# Count the Number of 'NA' in a single row - MySQL

Tags: mysql

If there is a row where there are more than or equal to 2 NA in two different columns, then I want to select that row and show all of its columns. Is there a SQL to do that?

Original Data:

```
 Overall_Score_ID   Company_ID  Operating_Margin_Score  Negative_Earning_Surprise_Score Acquisition_Score   TSR_Score   Enterprise_Score
 54                 399473107   0.0                     2.3770491803278686              5.666666666666666   NA          1.1475409836065573
 116                92847A200   0.3305785123966942      3.0327868852459017              8.75                NA          2.0491803278688527
 337                57164Y107   2.0689655172413794      8.85057471264368                7.558139534883721   NA          3.2558139534883725
 415                007767106   NA                      9.52                            NA                  NA          NA
 462                36112J107   NA                      1.28                            NA                  NA          NA
```

Output:

```
Overall_Score_ID    Company_ID  Operating_Margin_Score  Negative_Earning_Surprise_Score Acquisition_Score   TSR_Score   Enterprise_Score
415                 007767106   NA                      9.52                            NA                  NA          NA
462                 36112J107   NA                      1.28                            NA                  NA          NA
```

Right now I only have a query to count the columns and show columns that are >= 2 and I know it's completely wrong, but I am thinking that I can modify it to the query that I want?

```
select * from overall_scores
group by overall_Score_id
having count(*) >=2;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show what the input data looks like as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the input and output data. hopefully is a bit more clear now.

Comment: . . It would actually be nice if you put the data in as text so it is readable.  And, you can only include the columns that are relevant for the query.  Hint:  if you prepend a line with 4 spaces, then it is formatted like text or a table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hopefully I formatted it the way you wanted this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
select *, 
((Operating_Margin_Score='NA') +
(Negative_Earning_Surprise_Score='NA') +
(Acquisition_Score='NA') +
(TSR_Score='NA') +
(Enterprise_Score='NA')) as total
from overall_scores having total >=2;
```

Comment: I did not know that you can write a SQL like that. Learned something new today. Thank you so much.

Comment: You don't need the `case` statement in MySQL.  You can just write `(Operating_Margin_Score = 'NA') + (Negative_Earning_Surprise_Score = 'NA') + . . . `.

Comment: Even better. Edit made. Thanks Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query by changing the field names and table name.
It may solve your problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table1 
WHERE (length(trim(concat(field1,field2,field3))) - length(replace(trim(concat(field1,field2,field3)),'NA',''))) / 2 >= 2
```

you can find more examples like this on

www.csnotes32.com

Comment: Did not know you can do that either. Learned two new things. Thank you. I will save this SQL query in my list of SQL queries.